# How to create bubble or infobox left side of input type text

Tags: css

[image]

I am trying to get that Password meter to the left side in the info box which a triangle tip..

```css
.container {
    width: 50%;
}
.infobox {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type ="text" placeholder="password">
    <div class="infobox">
        Password meter<br>
        Uppercase<br>
        Special Character<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: position: absolute on it's own doesn't really say anything. absolute in relation to which element? how should it be absolute positioned (from top? from left...?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have work with `css selector` & `css pseudo`

```css
.container {
    width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  padding-left:240px;
}
.infobox {
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background:#fff;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
.infobox:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -1px;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: 15px solid black;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type ="text" placeholder="password">
    <div class="infobox">
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
        Password meter<br>
        Uppercase<br>
        Special Character<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am glad this helped up vote will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

this what you are looking for!

you can check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KOaXKR) for better result.

```css
.side-back{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  background:url("https://picsum.photos/1400") no-repeat center center;
  background-size:cover;
 }
.form-container{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.suggestion{
  width:350px;
  background-color:white;
  top:-20px;
    display:none;
  left:-120%;
}
.bar {
  height:7px;
}
input:focus + .suggestion{
  display:block;
}
.suggestion:after, .suggestion:before {
 left: 100%;
 top: 20%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.suggestion:after {
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border-left-color: white;
 border-width: 10px;
 margin-top: -10px;
}
.suggestion:before {
 border-color: rgba(108, 117, 125, 0);
 border-left-color: #6c757d;
 border-width: 11px;
 margin-top: -11px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row m-0">
    <div class='col-12 p-0'>
      <div class="form-container">
   <form class="w-50">
             <h1 class="mb-4">Sign In</h1>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group position-relative">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        <div class="suggestion p-4 border border-secondary  shadow-sm position-absolute">
      <p class="mb-1"><b>Password strength:</b><span class="text-success">Good</span></p>
      <div class="w-100 bg-light"><div class="w-75 bg-success bar"></div></div>
      <p class="m-0 mt-1">Password must be at least 8 Characters! At least one Uppercase Character and one Special Character</p>
        <div>
    </div>
  </div>
     <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-between">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Remember me</label>
  </div>
       <a href="/">Forgot password?</a>
     </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-4">Sign In</button>
     <p class="mt-2">no account? <a href="/">Sign Up</a></p>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```